How to get list of opened files in Delphi IDE
I’m working on an extension for Delphi, and I want to get a list of all opened files in the IDE,
so as it listed in Buffer List if I push Ctrl + B.
I attempted two methods, but they list only the files contained in the extension project, even if the project group does not include this project.
class function IOTAUTils.GetOpenedEditorFiles : TArray<string>;
var
  module : IOTAModule;
  editor : IOTAEditor;
  service : IOTAModuleServices;
begin
  Result := [];
  service := (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAModuleServices);
  if Assigned(service) then begin
    for var i := 0 to service.ModuleCount - 1 do begin
      module := service.Modules[i];
      for var j := 0 to module.GetModuleFileCount - 1 do begin
        editor := module.GetModuleFileEditor(j);
        Result := Result + [editor.FileName];
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

At least I can filter out invisible open files with this approach: EditViewCount > 0
class function IOTAUTils.GetOpenedEditBuffers: TArray<string>;
var
  service : IOTAEditorServices;
  it : IOTAEditBufferIterator;
  buffer : IOTAEditBuffer;
begin
  Result := [];
  service := (BorlandIDEServices as IOTAEditorServices);
  if Assigned(service) then begin
    if (service.GetEditBufferIterator(it)) then begin
      for var i := 0 to it.Count - 1 do begin
        buffer := it.EditBuffers[i];
        if buffer.EditViewCount > 0 then begin // if view count = 0, it is not shown between tabs
          Result := Result + [buffer.FileName];
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

What is the proper way to get the desired list of open files?

After some sleep and rebooting both IDE and PC, the second method above
IOTAUtils.GetOpenedEditBuffers
still works as expected.
